# How to use calldata return values in Solidity and when are they useful?

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Storage {

    string[] messages;

    uint256 bidPrice;

    constructor() payable  {
        bidPrice = msg.value * 10001 / 10000;
    }

    function store(string calldata message) public payable {
        if (msg.value < bidPrice) revert( "Payment not enough" );
        messages.push(message);
        bidPrice = bidPrice * 10001 / 10000;
    }

    function retrieve(uint index) public view returns (string calldata){
        return messages[index];
    }
```

Getting error:

```
TypeError: Return argument type string storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) string calldata.
  --> contracts/1_Storage.sol:20:16:
   |
20 |         return messages[index];
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It just works with `memory string` as return type, but:

- Why do I get the error?
- Is it useful to have a `calldata` return type? In what scenario?

Answer (score 5):

`calldata` only applies to input parameters. It doesn't apply to returned values.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I get the error?

You're trying to return a value that's in storage rather than in calldata. For it to work the compiler would have to copy your string to the calldata area and that's impossible because calldata is read-only. With memory that's not a problem.

If you already have something in calldata though, you can return it. For example here's a function that will return a slice of a calldata string:

```solidity
function substring(string calldata input, uint begin, uint end)
    public
    view
    returns (string calldata)
{
    return input[begin:end];
}
```

> Is it useful to have a `calldata` return type? In what scenario?

Returning something that's already in calldata is cheaper than returning `memory` values because the compiler can skip ABI encoding. You definitely want to do this if you can.

Having said that, opportunities to actually apply this optimization aren't all that common. It's very situational. Here are some examples I can think of off the top of my head:

- **Narrowing down the return type in an overriding function**. It's possible to replace `memory` with `calldata` when overriding, so you can have a generic function that returns a `memory` value in your interface and then use `calldata` in a specific implementation that just happens to do nothing with its input and returns it unchanged.
- **Encapsulating calldata logic**. In some cases you might have a bit of logic that just extracts something from calldata before further processing. For example your function might only need a slice of a bigger array and determining which part it is might be complex enough to warrant putting the slicing logic a separate function. Without `calldata` returns the function would have to copy the whole slice to memory. You could instead return offset and length of the slice but that's basically what a `calldata` slice is internally. The compiler can do it for you.
- **Lazy ABI decoding with raw input**. If your contract implements custom decoding logic, being able to fully operate on `calldata` values, including returning them and storing them in local variables, allows you to keep some advantages you normally get when you stick to the type system. One of them is the fact that the `calldata` values do not get decoded until you actually use them. You don't get that with `abi.decode()` because it eagerly decodes into memory.

  Here's an example that accepts a struct encoded inside a raw `bytes` array and extracts it into `calldata` variable:

  ```solidity
  contract C {
      struct S {
          uint x;
      }

      function convertToS(bytes calldata input) internal pure returns (S calldata result) {
          assembly {
              result := input.offset
          }
      }

      function run(bytes calldata input) external pure returns (S calldata result) {
          S calldata s = convertToS(input[32:]);
          return s;
      }
  }
  ```

There might be more but I think you get the idea. It's not a feature used very often but sometimes it's nice to have.